# Get a child node to be displayed inside an Anchor Pane in Java FX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

Just for testing I want a **`Button`** which is a **`Node`** so far to be inside a **`TitledPane`** (I know it contains an **`AnchorPane`**).

This is the general code I'm trying for the method:

```
@FXML private void alterarTitledPane(MouseEvent event) {

        if (event.isShiftDown()) {

            // Here is where I code for adding a button inside TitledPane                
        }

        if (!titledPane.isExpanded()) {

            titledPane.setExpanded(true);
            titledPane.setText("Expandido");
        }

        else {

            titledPane.setExpanded(false);
            titledPane.setText("No expandido");
        }
}
```

These are the two alternatives I've tried for achieving it:

> **Alternative 1**

```
((AnchorPane)titledPane.getContent()).getChildren().add(button2);
button2.toFront();
button2.setVisible(true);
```

> **Alternative 2**

```
Group a = new Group(button2);
((AnchorPane)titledPane.getContent()).getChildren().add(a);
button2.toFront();
button2.setVisible(true);
```

Got not results so far...

Comment: The codes seem ok. It is difficult to tell the problem without seeing the whole code. Create a new fresh project and copy into it only related parts like titledpane, anchorpane and fxml, then try again. If the problem persists post that project here.

Comment: Strangely it worked then! Now the question is ***why?***

Answer (score 1):

for add node in pane first of all you have to initalize it...
try this....its work.

```
AnchorPane anch = new AnchorPane();
Button btn = new Button("anshul");
anch.getChildren().add(btn);
```

Comment: Well I'm doing with through `FXMLLoaders`, I design Scenes in SceneBuilder

Comment: yeah its fine...so when you take a controller define its fxid in inspector code selection....then copy the hole code from view->show sample controller selection...and paste it in your controller file then its perfectly work

Answer (score 0):

```
Anchorpane pane=new Anchorpane();  
Label lbl_user=new Label("Username");  
Textfield txt=new Textfield();  
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(lbl_user, 10.0);  
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(lbl_user 10.0);  
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(txt, 40.0);  
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(txt,10.0);  
panegetChildren().addAll(lbl_user,txt);
```